# Why do I have missing textures?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I have read up that if your render has a pink texture to it, it usually means that it's got missing textures. I have imported textures but have replaced them with my own materials. However, in this case I have been able to render it perfectly fine until today when it looks like this. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that Blender has not lost the path to your image textures? A good way to keep them with the blend file is to pack them within the file

Comment: I thought that as well but once I went into the shading mode no blue texture was there, which usually happens when Blender looses the path to the image texture.

Comment: Pink is the color of missing texture data - not blue.

Comment: How helpful of you

Answer (score 0):

I think packing should be used only when transferring data to a different machine, otherwise it makes files bulkier for nothing. There are other ways to check your missing files.

File > External Data > Report Missing Files should tell you exactly which files are missing and where Blender is expecting them. You can open the Info Editor to see the full list if there's a lot of them.

If you know where those files should be, you can tell Blender where to find them using File > External Data > Relocate Missing Files. Repeat this for every folder of missing files.

In a normal scenario, you should never edit the names or change the location of files you are using in a project.
There are ways to help avoid that. Making a copy of the files in a subfolder next to the project file, for example. Using relative paths instead of absolute also allows you to move the files while maintaining the link - as long as the relative path is maintained (which is easy when you have everything in a folder, and you move only that folder or its parents).